# Benchmarking PHP memory use across multiple servers?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, nginx, benchmark

I have a Drupal website that I've done quite a lot of optimization to in order to reduce memory usage, but it's still running at ~50MB peak per non-cached page load.

Given that I've run it on a local dev machine (Mac OS X 10.6 running MAMP w/ Apache2 and PHP 5.2.17 with XCache and Zend Optimizer) and on another webhost (A CentOS 5.8 machine running Apache2, PHP 5.2.17 with Zend Optimizer) -- which used 14mb and around 30mb respectively -- I'm getting the sneaky suspicion the issue lies with my present webhost (Running Nginx on Debian 6 with PHP 5.2.17 with Zend Optimizer and XCache).

**Is there any way of easily benchmarking PHP memory usage across varying server configuration?**

Thanks!

Comment: Should also add this webhost (**coughcoughDreamhostcoughcough**) is also hosting another website on an unrelated account that is spiking above 500mb (on Apache2) for a really no-thrills WordPress website that is receiving very little traffic at the moment. My suspicion is that PHP is just -- on a whole -- really poorly configured over there...

Answer (score -2):

Check hosting points:

1. linked modules
2. PHP.INI variable "memory_limit"
3. memory limits in Zend module

All of that parameters you can see via script

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
```

Comment: What does this have to do with my question? Genuinely confused.